# Show alert in present activity by other device using a Bluetooth chat example

Tags: android

I am developing a Bluetooth chat application with the help of the Bluetooth chat application on the Android developer site.

I did some modifications in existing code as when I send Bluetooth chat requests to another device (assume we are paired previously) and request receiving device resides in any activity.

I want to display an alert to the current displaying screen, but I am getting an alert at a particular activity only. So I am getting stuck. My code is below for the sender and receiver side:

```
if (FaceCardList.requestConnection &&
    FaceCardList.deviceSelected) {

    String authorization = "messagetype:startChat,"
                            + FaceCardList.ScreenName;
    FaceCardList.this.sendMessage(authorization);
}
```

On the receiving side:

```
if (readMessage.indexOf("messagetype:startChat") != -1) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
        new AlertDialog.Builder(FaceCardList.this);
    builder.setMessage(
        FaceCardList.screennmname + " wants to chat with you")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent serverIntent = new Intent(
                            FaceCardList.this,
                            BluetoothChat.class);
                    startActivity(serverIntent);

                    String authorization = "messagetype:initiatechat";
                    FaceCardList.this
                            .sendMessage(authorization);
                }
            })
        .setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(
                        DialogInterface diaLog,
                        int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String authorization = "messagetype:stopservice";
                    FaceCardList.this
                            .sendMessage(authorization);

                    FaceCardList.mChatService.stop();
                    FaceCardList.mChatService.start();
                }
            });
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one central communication activity which is receiving requests you may just use a Handler to communicate with any other activity easily.

See here for reference:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

There are many tutorials and examples.

Using handlers is extremely easy and yet flexible - it does not block your activity but allows any kind of communication, even passing parameters

You may create a central communicator class with static methods and send all your requests via this central point to dispatch to whatever activity you like depending on a defined logic within this one point.

Here an example for such a method with parameters:

```
  static public void sendMessageToDialogDuringChat(
        int msgID, String msgText, boolean statusBool) {
    if (theHandlerForScreenUpdate == null)  // you need to create the receiving handler within this class beforehand
        return;
    Message msgForDialogDuringChat= theHandlerForScreenUpdate
        .obtainMessage(msgID);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean(msgText, statusBool);
    msgForDialogDuringChat.setData(bundle);
    theHandlerForScreenUpdate
        .sendMessage(msgForDialogDuringChat);

    }
```

and here a handler to receive the message. Be sure that within the central dispatcher you have stored the appropriate handler which should receive the message.

```
  public final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (DEBUG)
        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
            "-> "
                + Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2]
                    .getMethodName() + " msg.what="
                + msg.what);
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_CONNECTION_SUCCESSFULL_FLAG: {
        boolean connectionOK = msg.getData().getBoolean(
            CONNECTION_SUCCESS);

        if (connectionOK)
            theStatusTV
                .setText(getString(R.string.connection_OK));
        else {
            theStatusTV
                .setText(getString(R.string.connection_NOT_OK));


        }
        }
        break;

        case MESSAGE_ALERT_FLAG: {
        ...start your alert here...
```

Certainly you could do all of that in the receiving class as well - depends how you need to structure your "special" communication messages